# Explicit constructor still allows for implicit conversion

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, implicit-conversion, explicit-constructor

I am sketching a small generic type-wrapper-template in C++14, that is intended to enable, disable, or extend the underlying type's interface using mixins.

Here is the code for this wrapper (stripped down a little):

```
namespace detail {
    /// Helper template that is forwarded to the mixins used 
    /// for the extension of wrapper<•> in order to enable 
    /// access to the actual type `Derived`
    template <typename Derived>
    struct Cast {
        using type = Derived;

        template <typename T>
        static constexpr Derived& self(T* self) { return *static_cast<Derived*>(self); }

        template <typename T>
        static constexpr Derived const& self(T const* self) { return *static_cast<Derived const*>(self); }
    };

    /// This helper template is used to derive from all the Mixins 
    /// one after another, making sure the constructor is mixed in as well:
    template <typename Cast, typename T,template <typename...> class...Mixins>
    struct wrapper_impl;

    template <typename Cast, typename T,template <typename...> class First, template <typename...> class...Rest>
    struct wrapper_impl<Cast, T, First, Rest...>
        : First<Cast, T>
        , wrapper_impl<Cast, T, Rest...>
    {
        using First<Cast, T>::First;
        using wrapper_impl<Cast, T, Rest...>::wrapper_impl;
    };

    template <typename Cast, typename T, template <typename...> class First>
    struct wrapper_impl<Cast, T, First>
        : First<Cast, T>
        , wrapper_impl<Cast, T>
    {
        using First<Cast, T>::First;
        using wrapper_impl<Cast, T>::wrapper_impl;
    };

    template <typename Cast, typename T>
    struct wrapper_impl<Cast, T>  {
    };
}


template <typename T, typename Tag, template <typename...> class...Mixins>
class wrapper : public detail::wrapper_impl<detail::Cast<wrapper<T,Tag,Mixins...>>, T, Mixins...> {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using detail::wrapper_impl<detail::Cast<wrapper<T,Tag,Mixins...>>, T, Mixins...>::wrapper_impl;

    T& get() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&m_buffer); }
    T const& get() const { return *reinterpret_cast<T const*>(&m_buffer); }

    template <typename...Args>
    void construct(Args&&...args) {
        new (&m_buffer) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void destruct() {
        get().~T();
    }

    ~wrapper() {
        destruct();
    }

private:
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> m_buffer;;
};
```

Now, I can mix in a construction form some type `T` using the following mixin-template:

```
template <typename T>
struct constructor_from {
    template <typename Cast, typename U>
    struct mixin {
        explicit mixin(T const& value) {
            Cast::self(this).construct(U{value});
        }
    };
};
```

So far this works out fine, e.g. I can wrap an `int` like so:

```
using my_int = wrapper<int, struct Tag, constructor_from<int>::mixin>;
my_int instance{42};
```

See a the full code here on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/oi4VmH). However, I want to disable unwanted implicit conversions, which is why I marked the constructor of `constructor_from::mixin` as `explicit`. But unexpectedly, the following seemingly still compiles without errors on clang-5.0.0 (see on [compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/DjXBiP)):

```
using my_int = wrapper<int, struct Tag, constructor_from<int>::mixin>;
my_int instance{4.2};
```

## Questions:

- Is this a bug in clang-5.0.0? It seemingly compiles with the expected failure in [gcc-7.3](https://godbolt.org/g/fRx6k8).
- If it's not a bug, am I doing something unreasonable (undefined, unspecified, ...) here that explains why it should compile despite the `explicit` constructor on clang-5.0.0? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding how constructor inheritance works?

## Edit:

As @someprogrammerdude has pointer out, I may be misunderstanding the `explicit` construction. However, I still don't understand why the above code should compile, while [this](https://godbolt.org/g/Ci47X8) does not:

```
struct foo {
    explicit foo(int) {}
};

struct bar : foo {
    using foo::foo;
};

int main() {
    bar instance{4.2};
}
```

It would be great if someone could point me to the corresponding sections in the c++ standard that allow the construction in the case of my `wrapper`, but prevent it in the case here

Comment: I think you misunderstand how explicit constructors work. It means you can't implicitly convert to a `my_int` type, but you do an explicit construction of a `my_int` object. The value `4.2` is converted to an `int` and then passed to your explicit constructor. To prohibit such conversions you might need a second constructor, with a template argument for all other types, and make it deleted.

Comment: I think all the mixin stuff distracts from the issue at hand, which can be summed up by `struct s { explicit s(int) {} }; s obj(4.2);`

Comment: Also note that GCC complains about the narrowing conversion in braces, which is orthogonal to explicit constructors.

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointer @Someprogrammerdude! Still, is there a way to prevent the construction with the implicit conversion in this case?

Comment: How about something like `template<typename U> explicit mixin(U const&) = delete;`?

Comment: Not sure I understand... I want to enable construction from one type (here int) but disable from all other types (like double). Should I add a mixin with deleted constructor for every type that could convert to int?

Comment: @Julian For your edit, it's the effect of [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions). Change to `()` will compile

Comment: Thanks. Still, it's strange how the list initialization work in one case, but not in the other. Can you expand on that?

Comment: @Julian Compiler is allowed to just generate a warning. In your particular case, it's because `const T&`, not `T`. For your question about delete, just add a templated constructor literally as Someprogrammerdude suggested. It will match exactly and be selected if there is a conversion for your original one. Since it's deleted, compile error.

Comment: Thanks @liliscent, the templated constructor works out just fine the way I want and solves my construction curiosity:-)

Comment: @xskxzr the storage is the `m_buffer` in the `wrapper` class. The instance of `T` is constructed there using placement new by calling `Cast::self(this).construct()` in the `constructor_from` mixin

Comment: Not sure I understand your last point, @liliscent. In particular, I don't quite understand what you mean by "Because of `using` of the same name will be shallowed". I'm explicitly importing the base-class constructors so they are visible in the derived classes (`wrapper<•>` in particular).

Comment: It seems `Cast::self(this)` will result in undefined behavior because the most derived object (i.e. of type `wrapper<...>`) has not been constructed when its base `mixin` is being constructed.

Comment: @xskxzr, yes, I'm concerned about that as well. Still, the most derived thing is supposed to be unconstructed at this point and I'm constructing the instance using placement new. But I can see that this may not be well-defined. Do you have any alternative ways of injecting constructor-behavior using mixins (or something similar)?